# Error while installing cassandra

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I am trying to install apache cassandra on ubuntu 16.04 LTS following instructions here -> http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/install/installDeb.html.

However I am getting the following error while running ***sudo apt-get install datastax-ddc*** command:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be
installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that
some required packages have not yet been created or been moved
out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve
the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  datastax-ddc :  Depends: python-support (>= 0.90.0) but it is not
                           installable  
                  Recommends: ntp but it is not going to be installed or  
                              time-daemon
                  Recommends: datastax-ddc-tools but it is not going to
                              be installed  E: Unable to correct problems,
                              you have held broken packages.
```

Is the datastax-ddc broken or something is wrong with my python?

Comment: try `sudo aptitude install datastax-ddc` ?

Comment: The same exception

Comment: the thing is, 16.04 just came out and it's not a stable version yet...

Comment: what do you get with `sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: No any exception. It upgrades bunch of installed packages including java and python 3

Comment: do you absolutely need ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I ran into this same problem a few days ago - python-support has been removed from 16.04 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-support/+bug/1535318

Comment: Version 3.7 from Cassandra from Datastax has fixed this.

Answer (score 8):

For now, you may run the following steps:

1) Download the deb package from repository

```
apt-get download cassandra
```

2) Install the deb file, ignoring the dependencies

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends -i cassandra_3.5_all.deb
```

Obviously, you should make sure that all the other dependencies are satisfied. The `python-support` is already included in a default server installation, so no worries, however, python itself may not yet be installed on your system, so you should run the following **BEFORE** the `dpkg -i ...`:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

To see the `Depends: ...` of the .deb before you try to install it, you may use the `-I` option as in:

```
dpkg -I cassandra_3.5_all.deb
```

In case of Cassandra 3.5, I see the following:

```
Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless | java8-runtime, adduser, python (>= 2.7), python-support (>= 0.90.0)
```

So you could first run the following to make sure all dependencies are indeed satisfied:

```
sudo apt-get install adduser python oracle-java8-installer
```

or if you want to use the OpenJDK (NOT TESTED):

```
sudo apt-get install adduser python default-jre
```

Answer (score 3):

The shorter version of the answer:
ubuntu comes python 2 and python 3 installed but not the python-support which is now maintained by ajenti. So to have cassandra installed properly (as normal procedure described in the datastax doc)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/766169/why-no-more-python-support-in-16-04

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajenti/ajenti/master/scripts/install.sh > install.sh && sudo bash install.sh`

`wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/109052632/python-support_1.0.15_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-support_1.0.15_all.deb`