# How to Install Cassandra on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-16.04

While installing Cassandra on Ubuntu it is throwing the exception as

> dsc22 : Depends: python-support (>= 0.90.0) but it is not install-able
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880886/error-while-installing-cassandra refer this link.

Comment: How did you tried to install Cassandra?

Comment: Using the APT repository (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/install/installDeb.html)